# How to completely disable ASUS laptop keyboard backlight (even when in sleep)?

Tags: laptop, sleep, backlight

I've used <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to turn off the keyboard backlight. This works while the PC is awake.

But when the PC is put to sleep mode, the keyboard backlight still glows on and off. How do I also disable this light even when in sleep mode?

(I'm using [ASUS TUF Dash F15](https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-dash-f15-2022/).)

---

In Armoury Crate > Device > ASUS TUF Dash F15 > Lighting > for each of "Static", "Breathing", and "Strobing", I've already set "Brightness" to 0% and under "Settings", also turned "Off" both "Awake" and "Sleep". But the problem persists.

Comment: 1. See https://thedroidguy.com/how-to-change-asus-tuf-laptop-keyboard-color-1146392 , to see if that persists when sleeping. 2. Check BIOS for a keyboard light setting. Or, 3. Skip sleep and  go to Hibernate.

Comment: There is a [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/ic25qh/support_keyboard_flicker_during_sleep_mode_asus/) saying that in Device > Lightning > Settings (found on top right),  you have 3 switches and you need to turn off the sleeping switch. I can't verify that, not having this laptop. You could also try [ASUS ROG Aura Core](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/rog-aura-core/9PG5Q8NSF0ZC?hl=fr-fr&gl=fr) to turn the keyboard off while sleeping.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but there's also the option of seeing if you can physically disengage the wiring for the LED back light?  If you're lucky, it might be modular and visibly discernible, but either way it goes without saying don't proceed without being certain you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly try hard rebooting it by holding down the power button until it turns off. Then maybe trying Armory Crate again, hard rebooting/restarting, and seeing if the issue persists.

If that fails (which it likely will), I'd try these troubleshooting steps I found in [this](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/keyboard-backlight-turning-itself-on-and-off.394645/) 7 year old Tom's Guide post.

**Step 1:** Uninstalling and then reinstalling the keyboard driver.

To do this, go to Device Manager. After that, update the keyboard driver(s). Then reboot your laptop. After rebooting, check if the problem is still there. If so, maybe go to Armory Crate and try turning the "Asleep" switch to off like you tried last time before continuing. If that fails, I'd try uninstalling and then reinstalling the drivers and then following the rest of the steps. As I've never done that before, you may need to backup or download the drivers online before you do this. However, I am aware there is an automatic option to find drivers online so I am unsure if that part is necessary.

If that doesn't work, I'd check for an option in BIOS. Unfortunately, I was unable to find much on this besides how to get into the BIOS (restarting the laptop and holding/tapping F2).

Step 2 was installing [this](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Drivers/ATKPackage/ATKPackage_Win7_32_Z100022.zip) ATK driver for your keyboard. Opening it in a new tab immediately closed it for me and it wouldn't download unless I was in the tab, which (sidenote) made me kind of worry about it, but whatever. Considering how old it is, you may want to find another driver online. If you want to do this step, install the driver, reboot the laptop, and see if the problem is still there. If yes, you may be worth trying Armory Crate again.

**Good luck!**